# How can I give a vets model a new shorter series to predict on?

Tags: r

This is the scenario, I have 2 long series from where I want to create a vets model using the R package legion, and a shorter series (say a new product which is similar to the 2 long series products but from which I don't have as much history).

I tried filling the shorter series with NAs until I got the same length as the longer series and trying to create the vets model but this does not work.

I also tried creating the vets model with the longer series and then forecasting with newdata equal to the short series and this also does not work.

```r
library(legion)
#> Loading required package: greybox
#> Package "greybox", v1.0.8 loaded.
#> Loading required package: smooth
#> This is package "smooth", v3.2.1
#> This is package "legion", v0.1.2

Y_short <- ts(2000 + 20 * 0:23 + rnorm(12, 0, 22), frequency = 12, start = 9)
Y_long <- ts(cbind(1000 + 10 * 0:119 + rep(c(0,100,200,300,250,200,150,100,50,-100,-200,500),10) + rnorm(120,0,20),
                   1000 + 30 * 0:119 + 2 * rep(c(0,100,200,300,250,200,150,100,50,-100,-200,500),10) + rnorm(120,0,21)),
             frequency = 12)

Y <- cbind(Y_long, Y_short)
m1 <- auto.vets(Y, h = 12, holdout = TRUE)
#> Error in if (any(correlatedSeries > 0.999)) {: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed


m2 <- auto.vets(Y_long, h = 12, holdout = TRUE)
f <- forecast(object = m2, newdata = Y_short, h = 12)
plot(f)
```

[image][image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>